# how to CONCATENATE array text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let the cell A1 has "abccba"
Now I write a formula in the cell B1 `=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))))` it gives value "a" or array string as{"a";"b";"c";"c";"b";"a"}
Now when I concatenate this with `=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))))` it gives "a" but I expect "abccba"
where am I getting wrong?
how to concatenate array string?
Thanks!
regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate doesn't accept array values as argument; it only accepts discrete text values. When you input arrays, it just takes the first value as you have already found. If you want to pass a single argument as an array of text and have the result be a single string of all those arguments, you have to use VBA. Here's a UDF that would do that:

```
Public Function JoinText(arr()) As String
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        JoinText = JoinText & arr(i, 1)
    Next
End Function
```

And here's the formula to put in a cell, which must be entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
{=JoinText(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))))}
```

Comment: Hi! is there any direct formula?

Comment: No. There is no built-in Excel function that can take a single argument with a variable number of items in an array and return a string that combines all of those elements. If the array is always of a fixed length, then you can make a very long formula to combine them. Can you try posting a question closer to your actual task at hand? The example you gave is a really complex way to get your original result. If you posted something with the exact details, we may be able to give you a better solution you haven't thought of.

Comment: Yes. Frankly shocking that Microsoft have not yet made this functionality a feature of the in-built worksheet functions.